# Файл пакета подписан неверно

Tags: unity3d, android

Привет, ребята!

Проблема такая: сделал игрулину, в гугл плэй она нормально загружается, но у пользователей при попытке установки пишет о неправильности подписи файла пакета ("Файл пакета подписан неверно"). Игра сделана в unity3d, кейстор сделал, алиас сделал, паблик кей вписал. В чем могут быть проблемы?

Comment: может изза того что юнити крякнутый?

Comment: есть вариант, что в этом тоже была проблема :D вроде сейчас поставил нормальную лицензию, не знаю, вроде должно быть всё нормально

Comment: купил? 400 уе?)))

Answer (score 1):

Такое может быть из за несовместимости версий. Была такая проблема когда людям софт ставил на читалку с ведроидром v2.3

Answer (score 0):

Проблема может быть в jdk7, какие-то версии не умеют правильно подписывать.
Сам недавно столкнулся с такой проблемой. Заменил на jdk6 и всё работает.

Comment: Даже сами разработчики JDK никогда не рекомендуют ставить самую последнюю версию JDK, т.к в ее стабильности даже они сами не уверены. Обычно, если люди приступают к новому, серьезному, проекту, они пользуются версией JDK N-1, где N, собственно, последняя версия)

Answer (score 0):

Ставим прогу ZipSigner 3 версию и файлы будут подписываться правильно!!!

Comment: Да и без неё всё прекрасно)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что вы использовали два разных ключа. А он должен быть одним и тем же для всех приложений. То есть вы должны были подписывать все приложения одним файлом .keystroke.

Вообще много времени прошло с вашего вопроса. Можете рассказать как решели это? Сам столкнулся сейчас с этим.